# running code chunks from Kolacyzk and Csardi's sand package

Tags: r, igraph

I am having difficulties understanding the operator `%o%`

```
same.prac.op <- v.attr.lazega$Practice %o% v.attr.lazega$Practice
```

Is this operator part of `igraph` or `sand`?

https://github.com/kolaczyk/sand/blob/master/sand/inst/code/chapter6.R

Comment: You should have been able to ask the help system: `?'%o%'

Answer (score 3):

`%o%` is the outer product.  It is `base` R. For example,

```
1:3 %o% 4:6
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    4    5    6
# [2,]    8   10   12
# [3,]   12   15   18
```

is equivalent to

```
matrix(1:3, nc = 1) %*% matrix(4:6, nr = 1)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    4    5    6
# [2,]    8   10   12
# [3,]   12   15   18
```

See https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/outer.html.